# How to use pip's version of ipython?

Tags: pip

I had a system ipython notebook installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 via apt-get. To upgrade the notebook to the newest version, I ran

```
sudo pip install ipython[notebook] -U
```

This installed version 3.0.0 of ipython. But when I run ipython, the old version still starts. What is the correct way of using the pip's version?

Comment: P.S.: I am interested if there is an alternative to using virtualenv here.

Comment: If you type only `python`, which version of Python does the interpreter say you are using?

Comment: System version (2.7.6) - but note I am asking about a specific package (ipython), not python itself.